# How can I print 3 different types of values in a sorted 2d list from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file where it is written the name of a person, num. pressups and num. pullups. This is the text file.
[image]

I need to sort the students in the number of pressups and pullups that they can do respectively. For example, Jack can do the most amount of pressups and pullups so he would be at the top for both categories.

To solve this, I think I should make a 2D list however I am unsure of how to sort to append the values in a sorted way. This is the code that I have written so far.

```
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
reader = opener.readline()
listObjects = []
listNames = []
listPressups = []
listPullups = []
while reader!="":
    splitting=reader.split(",")
    name = splitting[0]
    press_ups = splitting[1]
    pull_ups = splitting[2]
    reader = opener.readline()
    print(name)
    print(press_ups)
    print(pull_ups)
    listNames.append(name)
    listPressups.append(press_ups)
    listPullups.append(pull_ups)
    listObjects.append(name)
    listObjects.append(press_ups)
    listObjects.append(pull_ups)
print(listObjects)
splitting2 = str(listObjects).split("\n")

# print(splitting[1])
# print(splitting[2])

opener.close()
```

I would just like to know a method that would help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to do this with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your.csv", columns=["name","pressups", "pullups"])
df.sort(["pressups", "pullups"], ascending=[True, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', "r") as f:
    sorted(csv.DictReader(f),
           # replace with actual column names
           key=lambda x: (int(x["pressups"]), int(x["pullups"])),
           reverse=True)
```